# Netsuite: Any way to hide the center tab which seems like a customize tab

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

How to remove or hide the center tab? It seems to me like a customized tab. I tried to look into Customization> Center and Tabs > Center Tabs but no luck. I search through all the scripts deployment but do not see any related. They are just lying on the bar there permanently. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to hide these two annoying tabs from the bar. :)

You just have to navigated to Setup > Company > Enable Features and then under Web Presence Tab and uncheck the Intranet box as shown in below. Done.

[image]

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!  However, there must be something else going on here as well - I just checked our settings and the Intranet option is checked, but I've never seen those tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Hover on the custom tab you want to remove, say "Intranet", and the first entry in the drop-down should be the tab overview section - in this example "Intranet Overview".  Click that and look for "Edit Custom Tab" near the top right.  Click that and under Audience you can remove the role from the tab.

You can also get to the edit tab screen through Customization > Centers and Tabs > Center Tabs  as you were, but you need to make sure you're looking at the tab under the correct Center you're using in the role you want to remove it for, and then under the Audience tab you choose which Roles (or employees, groups or whatever) it will show for.

Comment: When I hover to other tab it will have "Overview" like what you said but none for this two customized tab. :(

Currently I am login under Administrator role, do you means that if this two tab are created under other role then even Administrator role not able to do anything on it?

For your information Customization > Centers and Tabs > Center Tabs has empty list in my case.